# How to write console output to text file in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am using Ubuntu, python3 and Flask server.
I simply want the line  print('**found file', file.filename, '\n') which is printed on terminal to be saved into a text file.

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory, jsonify
from werkzeug import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'mp4'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
  # this has changed from the original example because the original did not work for me
    return filename[-3:].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            print('**found file', file.filename, '\n')
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return jsonify({"success" : url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename)})
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Comment: If you are using Windows or linux

Comment: Why don’t you use flask.logger? I don’t see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a log file in append mode and add line every time print is called

```
with open("server.log", "a") as fd:
    fd.write("**found file {} \n".format(file.filename))
```

Or you can redirect the standard output to the log file when you launch your programm

```
$ python run.py > server.log
```